# ErrorException Undefined variable $request`

Tags: php

En el controlador recibo toda la información de los campos del formulario, pero el campo `email` no es reconocido dentro de la función `Mail::send()` me da el error `ErrorException Undefined variable $request` en la línea `$msj->from($request['email'],"Admin");` no obtengo el valor de `$request['email']`

```
public function message(Request $request)
{
    $subject = "Solicitud de avaluo";
    $for = 'mi_email@gmail.com';
    Mail::send('mails/value',$request->all(), function($msj) use($subject,$for){
        $msj->from($request['email'],"Admin");
        $msj->subject($subject);
        $msj->to($for);
    });

    return view('mails.sent');
}
```

Comment: Perfecto gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías pasar el `$request` como parámetro a `use()`:

```
use($request, $subject, $for)
```

use(...) se utiliza para que esa función anónima tenga acceso a las variables de fuera, en este caso, las que pasas a través de use().

Comment: Muchas gracias!